# How can I calculate the angles of two lines relative to the X axis

Tags: trigonometry, angle

Imagine a 4 sided polygon $ABCD$ with all sides of the same length and the point $C$ at $(0,0)$. Given the location of point $A$ (which is the top point of a rhombus-like shape), I need to find the angle of the line $BC$ relative to the x-axis (let's call it $\Theta_1$), and the angle of the line $CD$ relative to the x-axis (let's this one $\Theta_2$)

Some constraints:

- $C$ (the bottom point) will always be located at $(0,0)$
- We will always know the location of $A$
- $BC$ will *never* cross $CD$
- All sides will always be the exact same length
- $\Theta_1$ and $\Theta_2$ will always be positive or 0.

My only thinking is that we can always treat the shape as a symmetrical rhombus with some additional rotation applied, so if we can calculate the inner angle of $C$, we can subtract that from 180 to get $\Theta_1$+$\Theta_2$

If we can also calculate the rotation of the rhombus, we can then figure out what $\Theta_1$ and $\Theta_2$ are.

This math is probably relatively simple to all you geniuses out there, but I haven't learned trigonometry yet (I'm going into HS this year) so I can't really wrap my head around it. Also sorry if I'm not denoting variables and things correctly, I've never used mathjax before.

I've searched the web and have found nothing about this. Perhaps I'm using the wrong search terms? Pointing me towards a useful resource would be sufficient, as well.

Comment: Do you know anything about simple trigonometric functions, like $\sin$ and $\arcsin$? Without that, there is no way to relate distances and angles.

Comment: @Andrei I sort of understand what they do, but not how to implement them. I understand that the solution will involve a good amount of trigonometry but that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: Just to be clear, you must also know the exact length of the four sides. Just knowing that they are equal will not be sufficient.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales yes, I can know that value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the sides are equal, you have a rhombus. You know that $C$ is at the origin, and point $A$ is at some (known) $(x_A,y_A)$ position. Draw the perpendicular from $A$ to the $x$ axis. Let's call the intersection point $P$. Then $\triangle APC$ is a right angle triangle, with the right angle at $P$. The tangent function relates the angle between $AC$ and $PC$ to the coordinates of $A$.$$\tan \Theta_0=\frac{AP}{PC}=\frac{x_A}{y_A}$$ The inverse of $\tan$ function would give you the angle. Note that points in opposite quadrants have the same tangent. So if you write some computer code, use the $\operatorname{atan2}$ function to get the angle.

Now we should look at the angle between the side of the rhombus and the diagonal. In $\triangle ABC$ you know the length of two sides (say $L$), and the length $AC$ from Pythagora's theorem:
$$AC=\sqrt{x_A^2+y_A^2}$$
Draw a perpendicular from $B$ to $AC$. The intersection is $M$, the middle of $AC$. Then $\triangle CMB$ is a right angle triangle. Since you know one of the sides and the hypotenuse, we will use the cosine function to relate them. $$\angle BCM=\Delta\Theta\\\cos\Delta\Theta=\frac{CM}{BC}=\frac{\frac12\sqrt{x_A^2+y_A^2}}{L}$$
And $\Delta\Theta$ is given by the inverse function:
$$\Delta\Theta=\arccos\frac{\sqrt{x_A^2+y_A^2}}{2L}$$
Then $$\Theta_{1,2}=\Theta_0\pm\Delta\Theta$$

Comment: Could you put the final equations to calculate $\Theta_1$ and $\Theta_2$?

Comment: $\Theta_1=\Theta_0-\Delta\Theta$, $\Theta_2=\Theta_0+\Delta\Theta$. @REMCodes Is this what you asked?

Comment: what is $\Theta_0$?

Comment: The angle that the diagonal $AC$ makes with the x-axis. See the first paragraph and the first formula.

Comment: I need to use this formula in a computer program, so I can't really 'draw lines'... how would I find the middle point without drawing a line perpendicular to B? I can only work with numbers in the program, so drawing lines, either imaginatively or literally, isn't an option.

Comment: I use the middle point just for deriving the formula. Just look at the last formula where I write $\Delta\Theta$ in terms of the position of $A$ and the size of the side of the rhombus

Comment: Ohh, thank you!